# Copy CSV File into Temporary Table

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a temporary table with 4 columns

```
 CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_import (
        a varchar(128), 
        b varchar, 
        c varchar(256), 
        d integer default null
        ) ON COMMIT DROP
```

I would like to copy data from a csv file into this temp table with command

```
COPY tmp_import FROM STDIN WITH ( DELIMITER ';', FORMAT 'csv', ENCODING 'UTF-8', HEADER 'true')
```

The CSV file header might have 3 or 4 columns like **a;b;c;d** or **a;b;c**, d column is optional. Like below;

```
a;b;c;d
31641212545;2021-01-01 11:00:00;http://www.google.nl;1
31641342545;2021-01-01 11:00:00;http://www.google.nl;1
31641310545;2021-01-01 11:00:00;http://www.google.nl;1
31641300545;2021-01-01 11:00:00;http://www.google.nl;1
```

or

```
a;b;c
31641212545;2021-01-01 11:00:00;http://www.google.nl
31641342545;2021-01-01 11:00:00;http://www.google.nl
31641310545;2021-01-01 11:00:00;http://www.google.nl
31641300545;2021-01-01 11:00:00;http://www.google.nl
```

The COPY command runs with 4 header CSV file but fails with 3 headers.

The exception thrown

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing data for column "d"
  Where: COPY tmp_import, line 2: "123456;2021-01-01 11:00:00;http://www.google.nl"
```

How can I fix this query or command to support both 3 and 4 headers and insert null for missing optional **d** header ?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, you mean that CSV file has to have fixed headers ?

Comment: Oh, I misread your question. Sorry.

Comment: @GaripTipici I think it was about the `copy...with (options)` syntax - it's valid [since 9.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/release-9-0.html#AEN102838), just not as common as listing options directly.

Comment: Bottom line, the number of columns in the CSV file have to match the number of columns in the COPY command. You can specify the table columns in the COPY command. COPY will not automatically adapt to the number of incoming columns, you will need to do that external to the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do both with one command, but you can instruct it to handle the second case separately: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Kdxi1Opn)

```sql
copy (select '') to program $$
mkdir /tmp/myimports/ ;
echo 'a;b;c;d'   > /tmp/myimports/mycsv  ; 
echo 'a1;b1;c1;1'>>/tmp/myimports/mycsv  ;
echo 'a;b;c'     > /tmp/myimports/mycsv2 ;
echo 'a2;b2;c2'  >>/tmp/myimports/mycsv2
$$;

COPY tmp_import FROM '/tmp/myimports/mycsv' 
WITH ( DELIMITER ';', FORMAT 'csv', ENCODING 'UTF-8', HEADER 'true');
TABLE tmp_import;
```

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | 1 |

Note the explicit column name list after table name:

```sql
COPY tmp_import(a,b,c) FROM '/tmp/mycsv2' 
WITH ( DELIMITER ';', FORMAT 'csv', ENCODING 'UTF-8', HEADER 'true');

TABLE tmp_import;
```

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | 1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 | *null* |

You can switch between these by catching the exception:

```
do $f$
  declare v_file text;
begin
  create temp table my_files(f text);
  copy my_files from program $$find /tmp/myimports/ -type f $$;
  for v_file in select f from my_files loop
    begin
    execute format($c$COPY tmp_import FROM %1$L
                      WITH ( DELIMITER ';', 
                             FORMAT 'csv', 
                             ENCODING 'UTF-8', 
                             HEADER 'true');
                   $c$, v_file);
    exception when others then
    execute format($c$COPY tmp_import(a,b,c) FROM %1$L
                      CSV DELIMITER ';' ENCODING 'UTF-8' HEADER;
                   $c$, v_file);
    end;
   end loop;
end $f$;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the CSV files has fewer columns than the table, you have to specify a list of columns, like

```
COPY tmp_import (a, b, c) FROM STDIN;
```

Since you probably don't know ahead of time how the file will look, you could proceed as follows:

- try to load the file with the `COPY` statement from the question
- if there is no error, you are done
- if there is an error, catch it and run a `COPY` statement with a column list